# Checkout layout block xml display two places

Tags: layout, checkout, xml

Inside the checkout, I wanted to add a shoppingcart in the right sidebar.
This works perfectly, but now the cart is displayed on two places. It is added to the right sidebar, that is correct.

But it is also displayed at the bottom of the checkout page.

How can I remove the element on the bottom of the page and only display it in the right sidebar?

```
<checkout_onepage_index>

        <!-- Block below progress block, inserted directly -->
        <reference name="right">

        <block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout_review_sidebar" output="toHtml" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/review/minicart.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item_mini.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item_mini.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/onepage/review/item_mini.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="checkout/cart_totals" name="checkout.onepage.review.info.totals" as="totals" template="checkout/onepage/review/totals_mini.phtml"/>
        </block>

        </reference>

        <!-- Block below progress block, inserted directly -->
        <reference name="left">

        </reference>

    </checkout_onepage_index>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<block type="checkout/onepage_review_info" name="checkout_review_sidebar" output="toHtml" before="-" template="checkout/onepage/review/minicart.phtml">
```

Just remove output="toHtml" on this line.then everything is perfect.